# Accidentally set write permission on sudoers?

Tags: command-line, sudo, sudoedit

I'm currently running Mac OS Sierra. I don't know exactly how, but somehow I've altered some permissions and think it'd be a good idea to reset them, but I do not know how. Each time I execute `sudo`, I am met with this warning: `sudo: /var/db/sudo/ts is group writable`

The command executes fine, but it seems to be a good idea to fix that. Please advise.

results:

0 dr-x------  4 root  wheel  136 Mar 28 11:34 .
0 dr-x-w----  5 root  wheel  170 Mar 28 10:38 ..
8 -rw--w----  1 root  wheel   80 Jan 27 00:51 zacadmin
8 -rw-------  1 root  wheel   80 Mar 28 12:00 zbrown

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the result of `ls -lsa /var/db/sudo/ts` to make sure that the problem is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will remove write permission from group on file `/var/db/sudo/ts`

```
sudo chmod g-w /var/db/sudo/ts
```